# Powershell - Append Variable to an Array using For Each

Tags: arrays, list, powershell

I'm currently trying to add a registry key to mutiple registry folders. However becasue you can't wildcard registry keys via group policy I'm using a ps1 script to add these keys. Essentially I would like to add a REG_Binary key with the hex value of 00 00 00 00 in this location: HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\name of outlook profile\c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e.

I have the code that adds this key on one profile using one line of PS. This is:

```
$path = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Name of Outlook Profile\c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e"

New-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 00030354 -PropertyType Binary -Value ([byte[]](0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00)) -Force
```

This works perfectly, however I need to do this on all folders in the profiles directory.
I can find out all the profile names in this string via this command:

```
$Profilelist = get-childItem "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\*" | select name
```

How can I add the value "\c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e" to each line of this array/list?

After adding this I will be able to use a for each command to add the key.

If anyone knows a better way I'm open to other ideas!

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way IMO is with a calculated property:

```
$Profilelist = get-childItem "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\*" | select @{n='extendedname'; e={'{0}\c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e' -f $_.Name.Replace('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\', 'HKCU:\'}}
```

Comment: This would work perfectly, however because the get child-item changes the start from HKCU:\ to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ I get the error message New-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software ... etc. Any ideas on how to change the start of the string so this command would work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles" | ForEach-Object {
    $path = Join-Path $_.Name "c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e"
    #Create key if missing
    if(-not (Test-Path $path)) { New-Item -ItemType RegistryKey -Path $path }
    New-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 00030354 -PropertyType Binary -Value ([byte[]](0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00)) -Force
}
```

Comment: This would work perfectly, however because the get child-item changes the start from HKCU:\ to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ I get the error message New-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software ... etc. Any ideas on how to change the start of the string so this command would work? Thanks

Comment: @user3290171 just replace it.

Comment: The problem is that you need to create the key first. Updated now